# Set different colour for Jquery mobile navbar

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I currently have set data-theme a for my navbar, but I want to be able to set it to a different colour. how do I do this? the navbar is inside the header. How do I override jquery mobile's css?

```
 <div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header" data-id="pagetabs"  data-position="fixed"> <!-- MyActivity Header-->
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="fb_feed.html" data-prefetch="true" rel="external" data-icon="fbicon"> Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="youtube_feed.html" data-prefetch="true" rel="external" data-icon="yticon">YouTube</a></li>
          <li><a href="my_activity.html" id="my_activitypage" data-prefetch="true" data-icon="maicon" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">My Activity</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- MyActivity Header End -->
  <div data-role="content">
   </div> <!-- MyActivity Content End -->
   <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"><h5>Social Stream</h5></div> <!-- MyActivity Footer -->
  </div> <!--End of page -->
```

Comment: see http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vGt2A/? navigate to see the difference. here is another example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7bdPD/

Comment: @svillamayor I have created a theme, but am having difficulties in integrating it together with what I currently have, I am also using jquery mobile's default themes want to be able to use them both

Comment: @Dot the tool lets you import the default themes and also create your own, so you can use both

Comment: @svillamayor I have transferred the unzip file to my server. should i only transfer the zipped file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/39/

#### HTML :

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left" class="custom-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" data-prefetch="true" rel="external" data-icon="fbicon"> Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-prefetch="true" rel="external" data-icon="yticon">YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="my_activitypage" data-prefetch="true" data-icon="maicon" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">My Activity</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.custom-navbar ul li a {
    background: #67497a; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient( #67497a,#946ab1 ) repeat scroll 0 0 #67497a !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( #67497a,#946ab1 ) repeat scroll 0 0 #67497a !important; /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #67497a,#946ab1 ) repeat scroll 0 0 #67497a !important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient( #67497a,#946ab1 ) repeat scroll 0 0 #67497a !important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( #67497a,#946ab1 ) repeat scroll 0 0 #67497a !important; /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#67497a', endColorstr='#946ab1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */   
}

.custom-navbar ul li a.ui-btn-active {
    background: linear-gradient(#5393C5, #6FACD5) repeat scroll 0 0 #5393C5 !important;
    background: #67497a; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(#5393C5, #6FACD5) repeat scroll 0 0 #5393C5 !important; /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5393C5, #6FACD5) repeat scroll 0 0 #5393C5 !important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#5393C5, #6FACD5) repeat scroll 0 0 #5393C5 !important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5393C5, #6FACD5) repeat scroll 0 0 #5393C5 !important; /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5393C5', endColorstr='#6FACD5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override `.ui-navbar a` class:

```
.ui-navbar a {
  /* changes here */
}
```

Or make a custom class:

```
.ui-custom-navbar {
  /* changes here */
}
```

and then add it to `<a>` within `.ui-navbar`.

```
$('.ui-navbar a').addClass('ui-custom-navbar')
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7bdPD/)**

Comment: I don't understand the long background url, can we not simple put in a hex value for the colour in the url and make it work?

Comment: @Dot I used a gradient background, you can use whatever you want.

Comment: I included this $('.ui-navbar a').addClass('custom-navbar'); in my javascript file onload. and added the style.. it doesn't seem to be working? :/

Comment: Have you made a new class? @Dot

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create your own top level class.

**Example:**

```
<body class="myclass">
```

**Some CSS:**

```
.myclass .classToOverride {
//some styles
}
```

Also, I notice in your code you don't currently have a class on your navbar. So you may need to add one.